# Android opengl GL10.glDrawRect?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to draw a rectangle using OPENGL in Android... Just a simple rectangle you know, with coordinates like : X, Y, Width, Height...

So I thought there was something like `gl.glDrawRect`... But nothing...

Then I thought about `gl.glDrawElement(GL10.DRAW_RECT,...)` but nothing here too...

Seems like, if I want to draw a rectangle using opengles/opengl

> I have to make 2 triangles oposite

...

Is that so, or does anyone have some tips for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, no native quads in ES.

You have to use two triangles [separately (`GL_TRIANGLES`), in a strip (`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`), or in a fan (`GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`)](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glDrawElements.xml).

[`OES_draw_texture`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt) may be useful if your implementation supports it and you're willing to put up with screen-aligned rectangles.

Comment: awww... Come on rly ? :( So complicated to draw a simple rectangle ?

Comment: Read [the spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf), those are your options.

Comment: @Cehm Well, since drawing a rectangle is not that usual, would be realized as two triangles in hardware anyway, and is not really complicated to achieve with just two triangles, it is no surprise it's not part of OpenGL, since it's not a general drawing library, but an API to interface graphics hardware.